# Anagrams code resulting in infinite results

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I need to generate anagrams for an application. I am using the following code for generating anagrams

```
def anagrams(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return s
    else:
        tmp = []
        for i, letter in enumerate(s):
            for j in anagrams(s[:i]+s[i+1:]):
                tmp.append(j+letter)
                print (j+letter)
    return tmp
```

The code above works in general. However, it prints infinite results when the following string is passed

```
str = "zzzzzzziizzzz"
print anagrams(str)
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I need unique anagrams of a string

Comment: Do you want your particular code to work, or do you just want a good way of finding anagrams in Python?

Comment: ``return word``: what is `word`?

Comment: clearly he meant `s`. the fact that he's calling a function in a `for` statement should have garnered a bit more attention.

Comment: why would calling a function in `for` need to garner attention?

Comment: @Kevin Guan - I meant 's' not 'word'

Comment: @Shawn Mehan - Is it wrong to call the function in a for loop?

Comment: Nope. Very useful, in fact. I've just never seen it done recursively in the control portion of the loop, rather normally in the body. In fact, I didn't know that it could be done. Usually the control would be a fixed value, like `for j in len(s)`. And even then that can lead to problems in different languages. If s is mutating, when does the control value of `len(s)` evaluate? Every run through the for loop? Or initially, when s was, say, `10`, but now is only `6` because of 4 elements being popped. Now you can hit an index out of bounds when `j=7` and in the body tries `s[j]`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed out that your code produces 13! anagrams, many of them duplicates. Your string of 11 z's and 2 i's has only 78 unique anagrams, however. (That's 13! / (11!·2!) or 13·12 / 2.)

If you want only these strings, make sure that you don't recurse down for the same letter more than once:

```
def anagrams(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return s
    else:
        tmp = []
        for i, letter in enumerate(s):
            if not letter in s[:i]:
                for j in anagrams(s[:i] + s[i+1:]):
                    tmp.append(letter + j )
        return tmp
```

The additional test is probably not the most effective way to tell whether a letter has already been used, but in your case with many duplicate letters it will save a lot of recursions.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an infinity of results, this is 13!(*) words (a bit over 6 billions); you are facing a combinatorial explosion.

(*) 13 factorial.

Comment: Hi, Correct me if I am wrong. I am not getting those many results, as I just copied this code and pasted in ideone.com and ran. I got few results. Please check ideone.com/EAOw2j and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't infinte results - just 13! or 6,227,020,800

You're just not waiting long enough for the 6 billion results.

Note that much of the output is duplicates. If you are meaning to not print out the duplicates, then the number of results is much smaller.

Comment: Hi, Correct me if I am wrong. I am not getting those many results, as I just copied this code and pasted in ideone.com and ran. I got few results. Please check http://ideone.com/EAOw2j and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Ok if you insist - you are wrong :) The `return tmp` is indented by a `tab` so is returning from the inner loop

Comment: I have corrected the code with correct indentation and I am able to reproduce the seemily infinite results now :) Please check the code at http://ideone.com/dAjkFa